# Como ignorar as migrations do django.contrib.auth?

Tags: python, django, migrations

Eu tenho uma aplicação Django onde pretendo costumizar a parte de autenticação. Já fiz o meu próprio [Backend de autenticação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/), bem como configurei o meu próprio Model que será usado na autenticação.

O problema é que, quando eu rodo o comando `python manage.py showmigrations`, está aparecendo as seguintes migrations:

```
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [ ] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [ ] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
```

Como é possível remover essas migrations do `auth` no Django? Eu pretendo usar um esquema costumizado e não quero deixar que tabelas denecessárias sejam criadas.

Observação: Meu arquivo `settings.py` está configurado da seguinte forma:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('app.backends.AuthBackend', )
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.usuarios'
```

Comment: Se não está usando nada do auth, já tentou simplesmente remove-lo do `INSTALLED_APPS`  no settings?

Comment: @jsbueno na verdade eu quero usar o Auth costumizado. Seria algum problema se eu usasse uma tabela com um padrão diferente do que vem no auth do Django?

Comment: se você eliminar ou mudar o tipo de colunas, o código do Auth do Django vai certamente quebrar - o que não dá pra saber é se só vai quebrar nas funções que você  fez overide e vai usar as suas, ou se vai quebrar em coisas que ele vá usar também. O mais seguro seria usar outras tabelas, que o Auth não "visse" - mas colunas a mais também não devem dar problema

Comment: @jsbueno a minha intenção era fazer uma estrutura de controle de permissões usando a base do auth do Django, sem pegar a bagagem toda (com o a criação de uma penca de tabelas que vi que o Django cria).

Comment: ele tem um bom motivo pra criar essa "penca de tabelas": é como a coisa toda funcionou, e bem, depois de décadas de evolução.  Ou você expande do jeito recomendado: herdando classes e colocando coisas a mais, ou faz outro do zero - tentar cortar pedaços do que está lá é receita pra desastre.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de dar o migrate dê o seguinte comando
`python manage.py migrate auth --fake`

Ou dê apenas nas migrations que você não quer criar

```
python manage.py migrate auth nome_da_migration --fake
```

Mas assim como o pessoal já comentou, cuidado para não estar reinventando a roda. Pois o que você está fazendo pode afetar a instalação de novas libs, atualização da versão do django, entre outros problemas. A boa prática nesse caso é extender as classes padrões do django e fazer as modificações que você necessita.